# How to make applicationn with Facebook API

Tags: android, facebook, android-facebook

I have made an application in which I have used the Facebook API. It is working properly but it shows me the Facebook login page on first view. But I want particular page of Facebook instead of the Facebook login page. How and where can I pass the URL of a particular page on the API of the Facebook login page?

Answer (score 0):

You are using the API incorrectly. The API allows your phone to have access to a user's profile data, not load pages. If you want to point the user to a specific page, you can do that through the browser. If you want the user to be able to post on a wall or do some other functionality through your app, you must get the data from the user in some way (through facebook's prebuilt dialogs for android, or your own GUI) and then form a request to the facebook API with the correct values.

See [the Graph API documentation](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/), which will tell you what you can and can't do with the facebook API.